# How to return customized JSON response for an error in django-graphene?

Tags: django, error-handling, graphql, mutation, graphene-python

I am learning to use `django-graphene` for graphql purpose.

For mutation, all I know is it would return error message of its own.
Let's say if I have a token field, and checked if token field is bad, I only know how to `return None` which would give the front end a query result of `null` instead of a customized json response for status and error

I have these codes

```
class ProductType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        filter_fields = {'description': ['icontains']}
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)


class ProductInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    token = graphene.String()
    title = graphene.String()
    barcode = graphene.String(required=True)


class CreateProduct(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        product_input = ProductInput()

    product = graphene.Field(ProductType)

    def mutate(self, info, product_input=None):
        if not product_input.get('token'):
            return None  # instead of return None, I would like to return error code, status with message
        product = Product.objects.create(barcode=product_input.barcode, title=product_input.title)

        return CreateProduct(product=product)


class ProductMutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_product = CreateProduct.Field()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `return None` you can throw an exception.  The exception will be handled by graphene and passed on as an error.

For example, `raise Exception('Error 123456')` will result in a response something like

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Error 123456'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "product": null
  }
}
```

The presence of `errors` in the output JSON can trigger the frontend error handling.

Please note that in general, any exceptions passed to graphql will be visible to the outside world, so it's worth considering the security ramifications of all of your graphene queries and mutation exceptions.